# wordpress: change order of publish meta box

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm building a site with WP and the Event Manager plugin, which adds several meta boxes.  Client wants all meta boxes to be in one column. No problem there.

But the Publish meta box is like the second or third box.  Way too high in the page, and above many of the Events Manager meta boxes.

I can "remove/add" the Publish meta box using the functions.php file, but no combination of $context & $priority variables move it lower in the page.

I have tried hacking the edit-form-advanced.php file in wp-admin, but there does not appear to be anything in there that controls the position of the Publish box.

I have even tried a met box order plugin but no help.

I'm sure you all agree that having the Publish meta box near the top of the form is unacceptable.

Any ideas?

I'm also posting to the Events Manager support thread, but hoping for some help here also.

Answer (score 0):

After additional searching and experimentation, this code added to the functions.php file in the theme got the Events Manager boxes in the desired order...

```
add_filter( 'get_user_option_meta-box-order_event', 'metabox_order' );
function metabox_order( $order ) {
    return array(
        'normal' => join( 
            ",", 
            array(       // Arrange here as you desire
                'event-categoriesdiv',
                'em-event-when',
                'em-event-where',
                'em-event-attributes',
            )
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: `get_user_option_meta-box-order_{CPT}` - CPT can be post, page, book, event, imaginary, foobar ...